# Android instrumentation causing services to restart duing test

Tags: android, instrumentation

I am trying to write an android instrumentation to enable and disable "Data enabled" in Mobile network settings. I use Robotium to help. Here is part of the code to trun on mobile data:

```
public class MobileNetworkSettings extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME =     
    "com.android.phone.MobileNetworkSettings";
    static{
        try {
            launcherActivityClass =                 
            Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MobileNetworkSettings() {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }
    ......
    public void testTurnOnMobile() {
        ......
        if(solo.isCheckBoxChecked(0)) {
            solo.clickOnCheckBox(0);
            solo.sleep(10000);      
        }
        ......
    }
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }
}
```

I plug in my 3G dongle, I can see the 3G network is ready. I can access the internet.
Then run the instrumentation. Mobile data network can not recover. And I see the following logs in logcat:

```
08-06 15:31:57.460: I/ActivityManager(2202): Force stopping package com.android.phone appid=1001 user=0
08-06 15:31:57.460: I/ActivityManager(2202): Killing proc 12129:com.android.phone/1001: force stop com.android.phone
08-06 15:31:57.460: W/ActivityManager(2202): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.phone/.BluetoothPhoneService in 0ms
08-06 15:31:57.460: W/ActivityManager(2202): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.phone/.TelephonyDebugService in 0ms
08-06 15:31:57.470: I/ActivityManager(2202):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{425f43b8 u0 com.android.phone/.TelephonyDebugService}
08-06 15:31:57.470: I/ActivityManager(2202):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{42468300 u0 com.android.phone/.BluetoothPhoneService}
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ActivityManager(2202): Start proc com.android.phone for added application com.android.phone: pid=15273 uid=1001 gids={41001, 3002, 3001, 3003, 1015, 1028}
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'phone' died
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'simphonebook' died
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'isms' died
08-06 15:31:57.530: E/jdwp(15273): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-06 15:31:57.530: D/dalvikvm(15273): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-06 15:31:57.530: W/TelephonyProvider(15273): onCreate: confFile=/system/etc/apns-conf.xml oldCheckSum=-1
08-06 15:31:57.540: D/TelephonyManager(15273): getLteOnCdmaMode=0 curVal=-1 product_type='' lteOnCdmaProductType=''
08-06 15:31:57.560: W/dalvikvm(15273): method Landroid/test/InstrumentationTestRunner$StringResultPrinter;.print incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Ljunit/textui/ResultPrinter;
08-06 15:31:57.560: I/TestRunner(15273): started: testRepeatTurnOffTurnOn(com.android.robotium.phone.MobileNetworkSettings)
08-06 15:31:57.560: D/TelephonyManager(15273): getLteOnCdmaMode=0 curVal=-1 product_type='' lteOnCdmaProductType=''
08-06 15:31:57.570: D/TelephonyManager(15273): getLteOnCdmaMode=0 curVal=-1 product_type='' lteOnCdmaProductType=''
08-06 15:31:57.580: I/ActivityManager(2202): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.MobileNetworkSettings} from pid 15273
08-06 15:31:57.590: D/pppd(13883): rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x4 "No network protocol running"]
08-06 15:31:57.590: I/pppd(13883): LCP terminated by peer (No network protocol running)
08-06 15:31:57.590: I/pppd(13883): Connect time 6.0 minutes.
08-06 15:31:57.590: I/pppd(13883): Sent 6815 bytes, received 4360 bytes.
08-06 15:31:57.610: D/pppd(13883): Script /etc/ppp/ip-down started (pid 15291)
08-06 15:31:57.610: D/pppd(13883): sent [LCP TermAck id=0x4]
08-06 15:31:57.630: D/pppd(13883): Script /etc/ppp/ip-down finished (pid 15291), status = 0x0
......
08-06 15:31:59.330: I/pppd(13883): Modem hangup
08-06 15:31:59.330: I/pppd(13883): Connection terminated.
08-06 15:31:59.340: W/Netd(1253): No subsystem found in netlink event
08-06 15:31:59.340: D/NetlinkEvent(1253): Unexpected netlink message. type=0x11
08-06 15:31:59.340: D/EthernetDataTracker(2202): ignore [ppp0] remove
```

looks like when I start the unit test, some service is restarted (phone,isms...) and Modem hangup, I have to unplug and insert the 3G dongle to make it recover.

```
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'phone' died
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'simphonebook' died
08-06 15:31:57.480: I/ServiceManager(1250): service 'isms' died
```

So my question is:

1.When I launch com.android.phone.MobileNetworkSettings, will the system really kill some phone related service, and cause the 3G dongle disable?

2.If yes, how can I do the test without impact the service? or How can I recover the modem by programing?

Thank you.